# How to check that dsn which is created used for Sql Server or Access using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I am making a program in which I established connection with sql server using DSN. I am using ODBCConnection class. I want to check that, DSN which is created is for access or sql server. I did google but not getting helpful information. I am using c# and visual studio 2008.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to have a list of System `DSN` then read registry subkeys.

```
 RegistryKey reg = Microsoft.Win32.Registry
                            .LocalMachine
                            .OpenSubKey("Software\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\ODBC Data Sources\\");
 foreach (string name in reg.GetValueNames())
 {      
   Console.WriteLine(name + " : " + reg.GetValue(name)); // name and driver description 
 }
 reg.Close();
```

Comment: I did not want to retrieve list dsn. I want to check out that dsn is created for sql server or for access.

Comment: @Awadhendra - You may compare it by dsn name and driver name.

Comment: I did not find list of all drivers online. Can you paste a link for all drivers which is used with Odbc data source.

Comment: reg.GetValue(name) returns driver description.